# Wordpress Multisite 404 errors

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, permalinks, multisite

I'm currently facing a wordpress multisite / permalink / rewrite rule problem.
My wordpress website use multi-site. I've got the 2014 website link to "exemple.fr" and the second website for 2015 to "exemple.fr/2015/".
As you might guess, I'm using subfolders configuration for multisite.

The problem occur on the second website (2015) which return 404 errors on every page except the home. The first one work as excepted.
What I have already try:

- mod_rewrite is enable
- my vhost file have the instruction AllowOverride All
- Here's my .htaccess file which is the default wordpress one for multisite with subdirectories:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

- The problem dissapear if i set permalinks to "default" on the 2015 website but my links are not like I want.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3):

Finally make it work after hours of trying.
The problem come from a conflict with the plugin "Polylang" (https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/). This plugin was install on the website and not even use or configure.

When the plugin is activated on the website and anyone save the permalinks configuration, it broke the configuration (in database the wp_option rewrite_rules was missing the "blog/" in front of all patterns).
Once we disable the plugin and save again the permalinks configuration it work again. I think no one have save this configuration since the plugin was install on the website, last week my client have probably try to change the permalinks configurations and stumble on that problem.

**Do not forget to try to disable all plugins when debugging a particular sneaky bug (and not after 1 day of debugging like I have done will be probably better), that's my advice !**